# Как одномерный массив преобразовывать в двухмерный js?

Tags: javascript, массивы, матрицы

Подскажите как реализовать функцию, которая будет первым параметром принимать одномерный массив, а вторым - желаемое количество элементов в подмассиве и преобразовывать его в двухмерный.

Например такой массив

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
```

а хотим получить

```
let array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4], 
  [5, 6, 7, 8], 
  [9, 10, 11, 12]
]
```

и чтобы не возникло ошибки, если вдруг нам не хватит элементов на равное разделение.

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм: проходимся по каждому значению исходного массива, проверяя при этом надо ли создавать новый вложенный массив. И вставляем в конец текущий элемент.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

function makeNestedArray(arr, pivot) {
  return arr.reduce((a, c, i) => {
    if (i % pivot === 0) {
      a.push([]);
    }
    return a[a.length - 1].push(c), a;
  }, []);
}

console.log(makeNestedArray(arr, 4));
console.log(makeNestedArray(arr, 20));
console.log(makeNestedArray(arr, 10));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь ))

Comment: пожалуйста.....

Answer (score 3):

Ещё вариант:

```js
function get2dimensional(array, limit) {
  const array2 = [];
  let section;

  for (const [index, element] of array.entries()) {
    if (index % limit === 0) array2.push(section = []);
    section.push(element);
  }

  return array2;
}

console.log(get2dimensional([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 4));
console.log(get2dimensional([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 5));
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь ))

Answer (score 0):

Так как задано количество элементов в подмассиве, можно воспользоваться методом [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), чтобы получить подмассив, с заданным количеством элементов.

В этом случае уменьшится количество итераций в цикле, за счет того, что не надо проверять индекс каждого элемента:

```js
function get2dimensional(array, limit) {
  const result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += limit) {
    result.push(array.slice(i, i + limit));
  }

  return result;
}

console.log(get2dimensional([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 4));
console.log(get2dimensional([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], 5));
```